# How to set value of textfield into the table column in java

Tags: java, mysql

how to set value of method in database using java code.

**mycode**

```
// for getting value code start here

 public void MethodOutputid(int num1)

          String sql="Select MAX(OUTPUT_ID) from OUTPUT_CONFIGURATION";
          PreparedStatement psmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs=psmt.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next())
          {
              num1=rs.getInt(1);
          }
                num1=num1+1;               
                txtoutputid1.setText(""+num1);
             }
```

//// for getting value end here

// for fetching value of outputid and set it into database start here

```
private boolean AddButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

                String sql = "insert into INPUT_CONFIGURATION (FILE_NAME,OUTPUT_ID)value(?,?)";

                String filename = txtfilename.getText();                    
                int outputnum=0;
                MethodOutputid(outputnum); 
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
                ps.setString(1, filename);                     

                if(Integer.parseInt(txtoutputid1.getText())==outputnum)
                {
                   ps.setInt(2, outputnum); 
                }

                ps.executeUpdate();
               }
```

// for fetching value of outputid and set it into database end here

here i am getting the **num1** value from the method **MethodOutputid(int num1)** as mentioned above 
and i am setting that value into **textfield** named **txtoutputid1** inside the **MethodOutputid(int num1)** method

now i want to insert the  value  of txtoutputid1 (a textfield) into table **INPUT_CONFIGURATION** in the **OUTPUT_ID** column.

i tried as

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtoutputid1.getText())==outputnum)
{
      ps.setInt(2, outputnum); 
}
```

i tried this, but showing error as  **No value specified for parameter**

wht should i do to insert value of that textfield (as txtoutputid1 mentioned in MethodOutputid(int num1)) in to the OUTPUT_ID column which is in INPUT_CONFIGURATION.

Comment: Please format your code - it's very hard to read with the indentation all over the place. It's also really not clear what you mean by "set the value of a method". Please take some time to explain clearly what you're trying to achieve, and what your code currently does.

Comment: He cancelled my edit.... thanks SO

Answer (score 0):

Your way of coding is not Recommended.

And About Error:
You have specified only two question marks in the query.So

You have to re write the line

`ps.setInt(9, outputnum);`  // You are not having 9 columns in your query

to

`ps.setInt(2, outputnum);`

Comment: ya its 2.. ma mistake actually der is a 9 parameters in my code .. to make it a small ..i  edited a code and forget to edit that 9 as 2..... it showing error as  No value specified for parameter 2 after executing. where am i wrong..in my code??

Answer (score 0):

You should set guaranteed value to second argument. Otherwise, prepared statement cannot be compiled. This argument may be left without a value depending of result of `if` statement in your code:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtoutputid1.getText())==outputnum)
{
    ps.setInt(2, outputnum); 
}
```

This's your mistake. Setting the value should be outside the condition. Leave default value or throw an exception in the case of necessary statement with comparison fail:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtoutputid1.getText()) == outputnum)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("error message");
}

ps.setInt(2, outputnum);
```

This should be executed without this exception.